# 'atlas.graph.index.search.map-name' doesn't map to a List object: false

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-atlas

I tried to setup the sqoop-hook with Atlas Following these steps :

1- Set-up Atlas hook in sqoop-site.xml:

```
   <property>
     <name>sqoop.job.data.publish.class</name>
     <value>org.apache.atlas.sqoop.hook.SqoopHook</value>
   </property>
```

2- copy contents of folder apache-atlas-sqoop-hook to hook/sqoop

3- copy atlas-application.properties to sqoop-conf-dir

4- copy all jars in /hook/sqoop in sqoop-dir/lib

But when I tried to execute sqoop import command :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://server/db --username user -P --table tab --hive-import --create-hive-table
```

I got the following error:

[image]

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the value of the following properties in `sqoop-conf-dir/atlas-application.properties` :

```
atlas.notification.embedded=false  
atlas.graph.index.search.backend=solr5
```